# Determining the group associated with a given potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, group-theory, group-representations

I'm trying to understand how symmetry groups are related to potentials of the Schrodinger equation. In particular, I wish to know if it is possible to find the symmetry group of this potential 
$$V(x) = A_0 +A_1x +A_2x^2 -\frac{9}{4}x^4$$

where $A_0$,$A_1$,$A_2$ $\in \mathbb{R}$

I've tried to see if it is related to the SO(3) group and the unitary group U(1), but neither seem possible. I asked this question because coming from a pure math background, I am having a really difficult time trying to understand this.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what to do. I'm a first year mathematical physics graduate student, and I was hoping that someone could offer a link that explains this.

Comment: I'm not saying you need to know how to find the answer, but if you've really done nothing at all, we're not really incentivized to help you. What is it that you don't understand about this question? Is it a term you're not familiar with, or a mathematical procedure you don't know how to apply? Which step confuses you? Some of the advice in our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) might be useful in improving the question, regardless of whether it's actually a homework assignment.

Comment: I'm more interested in the mathematical procedure to apply. I wish to know it for the sake of understanding research papers.

Comment: OK, well what have you done to try to figure out which mathematical procedure you need? For example do you know what symmetry groups and symmetry transformations are?

Comment: yes, I do. I've tried to see if it is related to the SO(3) group and the unitary group U(1), but neither seem possible. I asked this question because coming from a pure math background, I am having a really difficult time trying to understand this.

Comment: So you've tried some groups to see if they are the symmetry group of the potential? You should mention that in the question, and give an overview of what you tried to show how you determined that they don't work. Try to narrow it down as much as possible to one specific problem you're having.

Comment: Alright, will I'll remember that when I post here again. Do you know any books that give an overview of these aspects of group theory to differential equations or problems in quantum mechanics in general(specifically the schrodinger equation)?

Comment: Not offhand, but if you have access to [chat] that would be an ideal place to ask for suggestions for books.

Comment: @user119264 please edit what you said in the comments into the question. It is a legitimate interesting question, I will then vote to reopen when you have done it.

Comment: I would like to see the answer to this question. I sketched the graph of $V(x)$ and couldn't see any obvious symmetry. I assume the symmetry group is the group of transformations that leave $V(x)$ unchanged but it isn't obvious to me what these are.

Comment: Why should there be a symmetry groupSi

Comment: Why should there be a symmetry group? Since V is quartic in x you can write it as  V(x)=(-9/4)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4), where the x_j's are known. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @user119264: You may find Vedensky's representation theory page at http://www.cmth.ph.ic.ac.uk/people/d.vvedensky/courses.html to be helpful. If you are talking about affine symmetries such as $V(\alpha x+\beta)=V(x)$ for constants $\alpha,\beta$, then a visually obvious one occurs whenever $A_1=0$. Beyond that, it may take some tinkering.

Comment: Also, the $A_0$ constant is unnecessary, so you can just omit it. In the case where $A_1=0$, you in particular have that $V(\alpha+\beta)=V(1),V(2\alpha+\beta)=V(2),V(3\alpha+\beta)=V(3)$, so you can solve for $\alpha,\beta$ via `rule = x -> (a x + b);
Solve[((A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 == (A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. 
    x -> 1) && ((A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 == (A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. 
    x -> 3) && ((A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 == (A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. 
    x -> 2), {a, b}]`, which yields the parity and identity symmetries `{{a -> -1, b -> 0}, {a -> 1, b -> 0}}`.

Comment: You can play around with `rule = x -> (a x + b);
rule2 = {A1 -> 6, A2 -> 3, A4 -> 1};
Reduce[(((A1 x + A2 x^2 + 
         A4 x^4 == (A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. rule2) /. 
    x -> 1) && (((A1 x + A2 x^2 + 
         A4 x^4 == (A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. rule2) /. 
    x -> 2) && (((A1 x + A2 x^2 + 
         A4 x^4 == (A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. rule2) /. 
    x -> 3), {a, b}]` and change around the values of $A_1,A_2,A_4$. From experiment and visualization, it's apparent that the only symmetries appear to be parity (for certain values of $A_1,A_2,A_4$) and identity.

Comment: is it possible it could be related to the $sl(2)$ group?

Comment: I'll post my comments as an "answer" of sorts, maybe people can comment on it if they find errors.

Comment: Guys, I've made somewhat of a breakthrough. This potential is related to the differential equation in the last question I posted. If anyone can answer that then we'll have the answer to this

Answer (score 2):

This is admittedly an incomplete answer, as I don't work in this sort of physics, but a couple things can be pointed out. First, what kind of symmetries are you looking for? This is a 1-dimensional example, and it's not periodic, so unless you're looking for something crazy, the easiest thing to look for is an affine symmetry of the form $V(\alpha x+\beta)=V(x)$. Pictures may help:

```
Plot[x^1 + x^2 + x^4, {x, -1.5, 1.4}]
Plot[-x^1 - x^2 + x^4, {x, -1.5, 1.7}]
Plot[-x^2 + x^4, {x, -1.7, 1.7}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

One might conjecture that the functions either have no affine symmetry or they have reflection symmetry. I won't prove that, but I'll give code (explanation can be found in comments section) that shows this is the case for various inputs of $A_1,A_2$, and $A_4$ (obviously $A_0$ is irrelevant):

```
rule = x -> (a x + b); rule2 = {A1 -> 6, A2 -> 3, A4 -> 1}; 
Reduce[(((A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 == (A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. rule2) /. x -> 1) && (((A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 == (A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. rule2) /. x -> 2) && (((A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 == (A1 x + A2 x^2 + A4 x^4 /. rule)) /. rule2) /. x -> 3), {a, b}]
```

You will either get only the identity or the identity and parity transform for most values of $A_1,A_2,A_4$. If anyone knows a more rigorous way to show this, or sees that what I wrote is wrong, by all means post away. I think you can prove it by noting that if you assume the symmetry group is finite (which seems reasonable), then you must also have that the set ${x,T(x),T(T(x)),...}$ is finite, where $T(x)=\alpha x+\beta$. Since $T^n(x)=\alpha^n x+\frac{\alpha^n-\alpha}{\alpha-1}\beta=x$ for some value of $n$, you must have $\alpha$ be a root of unity.

If you temporarily rule out the possibility of complex-valued position, then it follows that the only possible values of $\alpha$ are $\pm 1$.

If $\alpha=1$, then since the potential is not translation-invariant, you must have $\beta=0$, giving the identity transform.

If $\alpha=-1$, then it's a little more complicated, but it's intuitively obvious that $\beta=0$ is the only possibility, since the potential is visually invariant up to a translation under a reflection if and only if $A_1=0$. So you get parity iff $A_1=0$.

Comment: The question is far away from my knowledge, but does every potential have a associated symmetry group?

Comment: Not really sure. In Vedensky's group theory course it's shown that the possible degeneracies of quantum states associated with a potential are the dimensionalities of the irreducible representations which are induced by the symmetry group associated with that Hamiltonian (or at least in the absence of accidental degeneracy). In short, degeneracy is usually a consequence of nontrivial groups of symmetries. Whether any potential has a symmetry might depend on how you define "symmetry", and I'm not a physicist (I'm a chemist) so I'm not an expert on this.